# Javascript modifying img src with substring

Tags: javascript, html, loops, iterator

i'm trying to 'cut' the hash of some urls in iteration, leaving only the img url (https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9Eu7SXGyvzQ/hqdefault.jpg) without the hash (?sqp=-oaymwEjCNACELwBSFryq4qpAxUIARUAAAAAGAElAADIQj0AgKJDeAE=&rs=AOn4CLDi79vN15idfFETvntyC9yat7FvZQ).

I got it working in this example (2 images) but in "real code" fail, as you can see they are still some issues in code I cannot figure out, maybe redundancy, not calling the src string correctly.

Need some advice.

Thanks.

```js
function changeSourceAll() {
var images = document.querySelectorAll("#img,.style-scope,.yt-img-shadow");
for (var i = 0; i <= images.length; i++) {
        var mini = images[i].src.substring(48);
        var source = images[i].src = images[i].src.replace(mini, "");
    }
}
changeSourceAll();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
        <title>Sometitle</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">    
    </head>
    <body>         
        <main>                  
                <img id="img" draggable="false" class="style-scope yt-img-shadow" alt="" width="210" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9Eu7SXGyvzQ/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEjCNACELwBSFryq4qpAxUIARUAAAAAGAElAADIQj0AgKJDeAE=&amp;rs=AOn4CLDi79vN15idfFETvntyC9yat7FvZQ">

                <img id="img" draggable="false" class="style-scope yt-img-shadow" alt="" width="210" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/gCI1L0gP-vk/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEjCNACELwBSFryq4qpAxUIARUAAAAAGAElAADIQj0AgKJDeAE=&rs=AOn4CLAUz6VUtsyrv5VZcfRvtnYM48ymHA">
                <script src="java.js"></script>
        </main>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have to use `substring()`? Try `images[i].src.split("?")[0]` FWIW, the part after the question mark is called the query string.

Answer (score 1):

Use a common selector to get all your `img` elements: for instance, you could rely on the class `.yt-img-shadow`.

Then use `split()` to divide each image src URL in two parts, separated by the symbol `?`, and re-assign the "short" version of your URL to the image.

```js
function changeSourceAll() {
  const images = document.querySelectorAll(".yt-img-shadow");

  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    const mini = images[i].src.split('?')[0];
    images[i].src = mini;
  }
}

changeSourceAll();
```

```html
<main>
  <img id="img1" draggable="false" class="style-scope yt-img-shadow" alt="" width="210" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9Eu7SXGyvzQ/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEjCNACELwBSFryq4qpAxUIARUAAAAAGAElAADIQj0AgKJDeAE=&amp;rs=AOn4CLDi79vN15idfFETvntyC9yat7FvZQ">

  <img id="img2" draggable="false" class="style-scope yt-img-shadow" alt="" width="210" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/gCI1L0gP-vk/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEjCNACELwBSFryq4qpAxUIARUAAAAAGAElAADIQj0AgKJDeAE=&rs=AOn4CLAUz6VUtsyrv5VZcfRvtnYM48ymHA">
</main>
```

Comment: interesting never occurred to me to use a split, added some modification split('/hq')[0]+"/hq720.jpg"; .o7